# How do I combine the float values of two columns and put it in an another column of my dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I am using the dataset- Meteorite Landings which can be found here- https://www.kaggle.com/nasa/meteorite-landings#meteorite-landings.csv

The dataset has a lot of missing values, after filling in the values of the columns- reclat and reclong, I tried to combine those in the form of strings and put them into the GeoLocation column.

```
reclat col:       reclong col: 


0    50.77500     0      6.08333
1    56.18333     1     10.23333
2    54.21667     2   -113.00000
3    16.88333     3    -99.90000
4   -33.16667     4    -64.95000
```

The problem is that the combined value does not show up in the desired coordinate format as I want.

I am trying to combine the values of reclat and reclong, preferably in a coordinate format.

Combining the two values in string form and inserting it into the GeoLocation column

```
data['GeoLocation']=str(data['reclat'])+str(data['reclong'])
```

I expected the column of GeoLocation to have values of reclat and reclong appended together, but it's in a different format as shown below.

```
0    0        50.77500\n1        56.18333\n2       ...
1    0        50.77500\n1        56.18333\n2       ...
2    0        50.77500\n1        56.18333\n2       ...
3    0        50.77500\n1        56.18333\n2       ...
4    0        50.77500\n1        56.18333\n2       ...
Name: GeoLocation, dtype:object
```

Comment: Why not simply like `data['reclat']+data['reclong']` this?

Comment: Did you mean to do: `data['GeoLocation'] = data['reclat'].astype(str) + ' ' + data['reclong'].astype(str)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, **typecast all the float values to string**:

```
data['reclat'] = data['reclat'].astype(str)
data['reclong'] = data['reclong'].astype(str)
```

Then, just add the value of two columns to produce output string. It will be appended.

```
data['GeoLocation'] = data['reclat'] + data['reclong']
```

I hope this is what you wanted. If not let me know accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I will take care to typecast next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
data['GeoLocation'] = data['reclat'].astype(str) + ' ' + data['reclong'].astype(str)
```

Please try the above code.

Type cast the columns and you can concatenate into a single column.